# Setitng up pre-filled Sqlite DB with Expo

Tags: ios, react-native, sqlite, expo

I am struggling to use a pre-filled db in my expo code. I added the db to the folder ./assets/db_name.db and then calling it in my code using :

```
const db = SQLite.openDatabase('db_name.db');
```

It didn't even reach the db. How can I connect a pre-filled db to an existing app?

Here's what I tried:
In my App.js I tried to copy the db to the SQLite folder where openDatabase is supposed to read:

```
const dbPath = `${FileSystem.documentDirectory}/SQLite/db_name.db`;


 const copyDatabase = async () => {
  const dbAsset = Asset.fromModule(require('./assets/db_name.db'));

  try {
    await FileSystem.makeDirectoryAsync(`${FileSystem.documentDirectory}SQLite`, { intermediates: true });
    await FileSystem.downloadAsync(dbAsset.uri, dbPath);
    console.log('Database downloaded to', dbPath);
    return SQLite.openDatabase('db_name.db');
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('Error:', error);
  }
};
```

and then call this at the beginning of `const App = ()`

It works "fine" when i run local `expo start ios`. I can call `const db = SQLite.openDatabase('db_name.db');`and perform some queries everywhere i want. But it doesn't work on android and doesn't work for a eas build. What is the issue?
I correctly setup my metro.config.js:

```
const { getDefaultConfig } = require('expo/metro-config');

const config = getDefaultConfig(__dirname);

config.resolver.assetExts.push(
  // Adds support for `.db` files for SQLite databases
  'db',
  // Adds support for `.ttf` font files
  'ttf',
);

module.exports = config;
```